# Tangent distance form point when rotating - formula

Tags: rotations, tangent-line

I have rotating tangent aroud center of circle and a viewer (laser distance scanner), which looks in one direction as in the image:

[image]

Tangent is moving counterclockwise. I need a formula to express distance of `Viewer` and `PointSeen`. I know length of tangent and I know speed.

Could you please give me some advice how to calculate the distance?

Comment: If Pointseen is at $(rcos(wt), rsin(wt))$, where $r$ is the circle radius, $w$ the angular velocity and $t$ is time, and Viewpoint is at $(V_x, V_y)$ then the distance is just the 2D distance between these points.. The length of the tangent is irrelevant.

Comment: @Paul PointSeen is intersection of `ViewLine` and `tangent`, whole tangent is rotating. `ViewLine` doesn't move.

Comment: OK. $P = (rcos(wt), rsin(wt))$ is the point on the circle with $w = \frac{v}{r}$ its angular velocity ($v$ its speed is known). This point has tangent vector $P' = (-rwsin(wt), rwcos(wt))$ and in vector form the tangent line is $(x,y) = (rcos(wt), rsin(wt))+s(-rwsin(wt), rwcos(wt))$ where s is a parameter. The viewline has vector form $(x,y) = V_0+p(e_1,e_2)$ where $V_0$ is the Viewer coordinate , $(e_1,e_2)$ is the direction of the line and p is another parameter. Equate the two lines to compute a value of s (or p) then compute $V_0 - P$ and its length d. If $(e_1,e_2)$ is unit length d = p.

Comment: It looks as if the rotating “tangent” is a line segment. For a not insignificant fraction of its orbit, this segment doesn’t intersect the line of sight at all. Also, does the scanner look only in one direction or can it see “behind” itself as well?

Comment: @amd It's not tangent, but line segment touching inner circle, you are right. Scanner doesn't see behind itself and it's even not important I think (behind scanner is nothing interesting). Actually, it's belt of carts and this "tangent" or line segment is one cart. So carts are not rotating around, they just turn around here. But scanner device must be here and I need to warp distance data to get "flat cart".